# выводится данная ошибка IndexError: string index out of range, что делать?

Tags: python

```
r = int(input("Введите размер поля "))
A = []
for i in range(r)
    for j in range(r):
        A = input()
for i in range(r-2):
    for j in range(r-2):
        if i > r-3:
            if A[i][j] == A[i][j+1] == A[i][j+2]:
                print(A[i][j])
        if j > r-3:
            if A[i][j] == A[i+1][j] == A[i+2][j]:
                print(A[i][j])
        if i <= r-3 and j <= r-3:
            if (A[i][j] == A[i][j+1] == A[i][j+2]) or (A[i][j] == A[i+1][j] == A[i+2][j]):
                print(A[i][j])
```

line 15, in 
if (A[i][j] == A[i][j+1] == A[i][j+2]) or (A[i][j] == A[i+1][j] == A[i+2][j]):
IndexError: string index out of range
выводится данная ошибка, я не понимаю что делать

Comment: что такое `A` -> `A = []` -> `A = input()` ?

Comment: это я создал массив, а потом заполнил его

Comment: Массив (на самом деле список) заполняется не так. Если хотите заполнить, пишите A.append(input())

Comment: И очевидно, что даже если заполнять как я написал выше, то двойных индексов далее не появится, т.к. для этого нужно как минимум один вложенный список.

Answer (score 0):

Замените

- `A = []` на `A = [[ None for i in range(r)] for j in range(r)]`
- `A = input()` на `A[i][j] = input(f"Введите A[{i}][{j}]: ")`

Comment: по заданию мне нужно создать поле для игры крестики-нолики на ввод я получаю длину поля(квадратное) и само положение поля(где стоят крестики\нолики\постое место нужно просто вывести знак, который победил(победой считается комбинация по горизонтали и вертикали, без диагонали) я немного не понимаю, как мне лучше поступить, думаю так: на ввод получить строку и через list разбить на символы и вносить в массив(я в питон пришел из java, немного не понимаю, чем отличается все от всего в питоне) идея пока только в голове, к реализации не пришел

Comment: @buzzinga  вы найдете все что вам надо здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D++%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8